# how to download a image from the webserver to java SE application

Tags: java

how to download a image from a web server to java SE application.

i have found the code for the ME application but apparently javax package is not in the SE developments. can someone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
       import java.io.*;
       import java.net.*;

       ...

       try {
            URL fileUrl = new URL("someurl);
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fileUrl.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/user/download/file");
            BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER_SIZE);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int x;

            while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                bout.write(data, 0, x);
            }

            bout.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can you please provide me the packages i have to use. im confused with what the packages are. please post them

Comment: Done. The packages are java.io and java.net

Comment: i tried this but still couldnt do get it working. can you please check. coz when i tried it. for all the steps its asking to put try and catch block. please do check

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons really makes it easy, with the static [FileUtils.copyURLToFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File%29) method:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

...

FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
```

It's part of the Apache Commons IO package, which can be downloaded here: http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi

Comment: this can be only to copy a file rite. but what my requirement is a bit different. i want to download and show a image from the webserver and want to show it in my java application

Comment: @Nubkadiya: true, but you can download the image to a temporary file and then load that file in your application. That will also help with caching - trying to view the file again in your application will use the local file already downloaded.

Comment: can you please provide me with the full code for that. its a big help. but i do need that code to get the data from that file as well.